# Polynomial of matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials

The question here is that,

> is it possible to solve a polynomial of matrix like the following 
>   $A^{2}+A=B$, where $B$ is a known semi-definite matrix, and $A$ is the unknown symmetric matrix we are looking for?

Any comments or links to references would be greatly appreciated.

Thankfully !

Comment: The quadratic formula works here as usual, reducing the problem to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix .

Comment: Thanks so much, Emil ! Appreciate that ! So, you mean the solution of the proposed question would be $A=\frac{-I(+-) \sqrt(1-4(-B))}{2I}$, right ? and then using the square root of a semi-definite matrix $B$ to get the solution $A$, right ?

Comment: In this case is probably not so important, but be careful: it does not make sense to divide by a matrix, you have to either left or right-multiply by the inverse.

Comment: Alternatively, change basis to make $B$ diagonal, and look for a solution $A$ which is diagonal, too. This reduces the problem to $n$ scalar problems.

Comment: I didn’t mean it *that* literally. The expression is $-\frac12I\pm\sqrt{B+\frac14I}$, which you get from $B+\frac14I=A^2+A+\frac14I=(A+\frac12I)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: $AB=BA$ and $A,B$ are diagonalizable. Then $A,B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. Then we may assume that $B$ is diagonal and we search a diagonal matrix $A$ (note that if you assume only that $B$ is diagonal, then $A$ is not necessarily diagonal !).

Step 2: as Poloni wrote, this reduces the problem to $n$ scalar problems in the form $x^2+x=\alpha$ where $\alpha\geq 0$.

Note that you can obtain (for some particular choices of $B$) an infinity of solutions in $A$.